# Magento Product Detailed Info - Restrict By User Logged in + Customer Group?

Tags: php, xml, magento

On my Magento product page I have a tabbed system in place to display the description, features and another tab called Downloads - this needs to be visible to logged in customers within a specific group.

In my Layout XML for catalog.xml I have this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
     <action method="setTitle"><name>Description</name></action>
</block>

<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.features" as="features" template="catalog/product/view/features.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle"><name>Features</name></action>
</block>

<customer_logged_in>
    <block type="core/template" name="product.downloads" as="downloads" template="catalog/product/view/downloads.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle"><name>Downloads</name></action>
    </block>           
</customer_logged_in>
```

**BUT -- Even if I am logged in as a customer in ANY group the box is not displaying, consequently removing `<customer_logged_in>` from there shows the tab + box.**

So I need to know:

1. Why does this not show when Im logged in?
2. Can I make this show when I am logged in - BUT only in a specific customer group?

I thought maybe you could use `<customer_logged_in setCustomerGroupId="2">` or something similar!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry I have now sorted via .phtml template files, code below for anyone else:

```
$_allowed_group_ids = array(1); // Stick in Allowed Customer Group ID's
$_product_collateral = array(); // We will store the tabbed content in our own array
$_restricted_tabs = array('downloads');

foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html) {

    $_product_collateral[$alias] = $html;   

    if( in_array($alias, $_restricted_tabs) ):              

        if( Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ):

            $_group_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

            if( !in_array($_group_id, $_allowed_group_ids) ):                           
                unset($_product_collateral[$alias]);
                continue;
            endif;
        else:
            unset($_product_collateral[$alias]);
            continue;                           
        endif;      

    endif;                                                                      
}
```

Example Usage:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $_product_collateral as $alias => $html ): ?>
    <li><a href="#tab-<?php echo strtolower($alias); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($alias); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</ul>
```

Example Usage for Box Content:

```
<?php foreach( $_product_collateral as $alias => $html ): ?>            
<div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>" id="tab-<?php echo strtolower($alias); ?>">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</div> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a Customer Login Redirect magento extension. It will solve your issue.

Comment: Did you actually read my question? I don't want any redirecting.... Just want to hide a tab if user is not logged in and not in the correct customer group.

Comment: You Can use login condition in view.phtml file of product if customer is login then display these things otherwise not